# Setup new device - old phone won't find the new one

Tags: data-transfer, setup-wizard

I'm trying to use the Google "setup new device" feature to transfer my SMS, apps etc to my new phone.  The old phone however won't recognise the new one.  Bluetooth is on on both devices, both are connected to wifi, and Location is enabled.

[image]

The old one is a Nokia 3 with Android 9 and the new one is an Alcatel 1X with Android 8.1.

I've also tried creating a backup on the old phone and using that to set up the new phone, but the new phone says it can't find any backups.

Is the Android version discrepancy the reason for this?  If not is there anything else to check?

Comment: I recommend to you to connect both devices via USB. Then those apps from PlayStore that can be migrated will be migrated to the new device.

Comment: Do you mean connect them both to a PC? Presumably I also need some software on the PC for this? (I'm using Linux)

Comment: No, directly connect both devices using an USB cable (and if needed an adapter). This is the way I know. Modern devices with USB-C can be directly connected.

Comment: ah.  No luck - USB-B on both

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a misbehaving wifi router might have been the cause of this.  A router reset fixed the problem.  It seems Bluetooth isn't enough for the two devices to see each other; a functioning internet connection is needed on both.

The restore still isn't working, but that's [another question...](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244412/setup-new-device-not-finding-any-backups)